# How to compare two values of type System.Object by value?

Tags: object, c#-2.0, compare

How to compare two values of type System.Object by value?

How to do the following:

```
void Validate(Type t, Object obj)//t is always a Basic type like System.Int32, System.DateTime, System.String, etc.
{
    Object value = Convert.ChangeType(obj, t);
    Object minValue = Convert.ChangeType(this.MinValue.Value, t);
    Object maxValue = Convert.ChangeType(this.MaxValue.Value, t);

    if (!(minValue >= value && value >= maxValue))
    {
        throw new Exception(".....err...message.....");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basic value types like `Int32` implement [`IComparable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.aspx):

```
IComparable value    = (IComparable) Convert.ChangeType (obj, t) ;
IComparable minValue = ...
IComparable maxValue = ...

if (minValue.CompareTo (value) > 0 || maxValue.CompareTo (value) < 0)
    throw ...
```

Answer (score 0):

`System.Object` as got no propertiese whoes values you can compare. surely enuf you can check the values that are returned by the function every object has.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the fact that the types you have listed all implement the [IComparable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.aspx) interface.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of object/var use dynamic ...

```
dynamic minValue = Convert.ChangeType(this.MinValue.Value, t);
dynamic maxValue = Convert.ChangeType(this.MaxValue.Value, t);
```